# Problems with java app and remote dbase

Tags: java, mysql, crash, performance

I'm having trouble with my java app on the database side of things. It uses connectorJ to communicate with a mysql dbase and works perfectly fine locally.  When communicating with a remote dbase, it performs dismally.  It's takes ages to start and windows that are supposed to open to display dbase data just say 'Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException' and prints a stack showing problems in places that work perfectly fine locally.  On top of that, features like search and uploads(based on xml-rpc) do not work at all but are fine  locally.  Am I missing something big? Please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried to connect to the remote database manually?

Comment: Yes I've done that and its working fine

Comment: I would start looking at the network, how many hops does a `tracert` show? Are any of the network cards set to auto-negotiate? etc.

Comment: Also, is the version of your local db the same as the remote db? You could look at an incompatibility issue Driver vs. DB

Comment: Does it "perform dismally" and give you meaningful results, or are you sometimes able to interact with the database and read/write stuff?

Comment: Sounds like sympthoms of nasty race conditions and non-thread safe code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated very carefully that you are not accidentially ignoring an error result or exception?

In other words, the code has told you something is wrong, but you keep continuing and you get lots of errors afterwards?